# Binary tree, example of tree with this same order for preorder and inorder

Tags: binary-tree, inorder, preorder

I want to ask you about example of binary tree that has same order for preorder and inorder.

My idea:

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbjIm.png)

In the best of my knowledge it is impossible to do any other tree.
I tend to think that tree can not have left side because inorder starts from left side and preorder starts from root, am I wrong?

Thanks for help

Comment: Depending on how exactly the question is to be understood - an empty tree or a tree consisting only out of the root might do fine.

Comment: Question was about series? string? of numbers when we read data from tree. So it should have at least 2 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The following class of binary trees provides infinitely many examples. For each positive integer `n`, let `{1,...,n}` be the nodes; the right successor of node `i`, for any `i in {1,...,n-1}`, is node `i+1`. Node `n` has no right successor and and none of the nodes have a left successor.

Comment: You mean tree like that from my picture but longer? Sth like http://imgur.com/a/hbGXc

Comment: Well, yes exactly.